# Flask app: bot not responding after sending message

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I'm creating a Chat app from a user to GPT 3.5 Turbo. But when I send a message, the bot never responds. Help me fix the code please. I spent days on it but it never works. Here is the app.py file(Note: I installed all the nessacary modules, the console installed them successfully):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import openai

app = Flask(name)

openai.api_key = 'MY VALID API KEY'

@app.route("/")
def index():
return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/api", methods=["POST"])
def api():
message = request.json.get("message")

completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
messages=[
    {"role": "user", "content": message}
]
)
if completion.choices[0].message!=None:
    return completion.choices[0].message

else :
    return 'Failed to Generate response!'
if name=='main':
app.run()
```

And here is the index.HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Chat App</title> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <style> body { background-color: #f5f5f5; padding-top: 20px; }
  #chat-box {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }

  #chat-header {
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e9ecef;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #message-list {
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .user-message {
    background-color: #ffc107;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .bot-message {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #e9ecef;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    outline: none;
  }

  input[type="text"]:focus {
    border-color: #007bff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5);
  }

  .btn-send {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  .btn-send:hover {
    background-color: #0069d9;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
</head> <body> <div id="chat-box" class="container"> <div id="chat-header">Chat App</div> <div id="message-list"></div> <form id="message-form" class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center"> <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Type a message..."> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-send">Send</button> </form> </div> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script> <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <script> $(function() { // When the user submits the message form $("#message-form").submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); // add this line to prevent form submission
// Get the user's message
var message = $("#message").val();

// Display the user's message
displayMessage(message, "user-message");

// Send the message to the server
$.ajax({
  url: "/api",
  type: "POST",
  data: { message: message },
  success: function(response) {
    // Display the bot's message
    displayMessage(response, "bot-message");

    // Animate the scroll bar to the bottom of the message list
    $("#message-list").animate({ scrollTop: $("#message-list")[0].scrollHeight }, 1000);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log("Error:", error);
  }
});
});

// Function to display a message in the chat box
function displayMessage(message, className) {
// Create a new message element
var messageElement = $("<div>").addClass(className).text(message);

// Append the message element to the message list
$("#message-list").append(messageElement);
}
});

</script> </body> </html>
```

I tried debugging it, changing the functions of the javascript but it still doesn't work!

Comment: Your `if name=='main':` is missing several underscores.

Comment: Yeah, thanks but I tried that and it didn't work, I don't know what is the issue.